# Find all the substrings in a string that only have a single bracket on both sides

Tags: python, brackets, regexp-substr, python-re

I'm trying to find all the substrings in a string that only have a single bracket on both sides.

Example: `'(pop((hello world))(goodbye(now))(hi)jump)'`

I would like to get this list: `['(hi)', '(pop((hello world))(goodbye(now))(hi)jump)']`
because they are the only substrings that have exactly one bracket on both sides.

*(substrings like `'(now))(hi)jump)'` don't count because they aren't complete)*.

My code here:

```
import re
l = '(M264/M274)+(((551/882)+362/(362/551/882)+889)/((551/882)+362/(362/551/882)+889)+(241/242/275/550/551+882/889/362))'
print(re.findall(r"[^\(.](\([^\(.].*?[^\).]\))[^\).]", l))
```

will return:

```
['(362/551/882)', '(362/551/882)']
```

I'm not sure how to make it include `(M264/M274)`.
Please assist me.

Comment: Regex is underpowered for balancing brackets. You should look into actual *parsing* techniques and libraries.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Is there at least a way to tell re to find all characters between 'a' and 'b', but not 'ca' and 'bc'?

Comment: To get your third match `(M264/M274)`, you could make user of lookarounds `(?<!\()\([^()]+\)(?!\))` https://regex101.com/r/PnvcnK/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird can you tell me my flaw?

Comment: @AnnZen Using a negated character class like `[^\(.]` and `[^\).]` match any char that is not listed in the character class and require at least a single char. This part `.*?` can match any char except a newline, so it can also match parenthesis. So you could update your pattern to for example `[^\(.](\([^\(.][^()]*[^\).]\))[^\).]` https://regex101.com/r/CNmgbM/1 But then you will see that if there are 2 `(362/551/882)(362/551/882)` after each other, you will only match one. You can prevent that using lookaround assertions, as they are non consuming.

Comment: Note that my suggesion does not take balanced parenthesis into account, only `I'm trying to find all the substrings in a string that only have a single bracket on both sides.`

Comment: How can I make this work? `re.findall(r"(?<!\()\(\([^()]+\)\)(?!\))", l)` this time, find all the substrings with double brackets?

Comment: It works right? https://regex101.com/r/SkeFsS/1

Comment: I see, but it doesn't work for this `'(M264/M274)+(((551/882)+362/(362/551/882)+889)/((551/882)+362/(362/551/882)+889)+(241/242/275/550/551+882/889/362))'`?

Comment: Doe you mean like this? `(?<!\()\(\((?!\().*?\)(?<!\).)\)(?!\))` https://regex101.com/r/19mJNF/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a negated character class like `[^\(.]` and `[^\).]` match any char that is not listed in the character class and require at least a single char. This part .*? can match any char except a newline, so it can also match parenthesis.

It does not take balanced parenthesis into account, but if you want to match `(M264/M274)` like in your question, you could use lookarounds in combination with a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

```
(?<!\()\([^()]+\)(?!\))
```

*In parts*

- `(?<!\()` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not `(`
- `\(` Match `(`
- `[^()]+` Match any char except `(` or `)`
- `\)` Match `)`
- `(?!\))` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not `)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PnvcnK/1)

If you want to match 2 opening and closing parenthesis, you can also make use of lookarounds and note that this also does not take balanced parenthesis into account.

```
(?<!\()\(\((?!\().*?\)\)(?<!\)..)(?!\))
```

*In parts (using the same mechanism or lookarounds, only this time using `.*?`*

- `(?<!\()` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not `(`
- `\(\(` Match `((`
- `(?!\))` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not `)
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `\)\)` Match `))`
- `(?<!\)..)` Negative lookbehind, assert not a `)` before `))`
- `(?!\))` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not `)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SuRXpa/1)